# Kotlin requires explicit cast to Object

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write a method in Kotlin that returns an object of type `Object`.

In Java I would simply write this as

```
public Object test() {
    return "Bla";
}
```

However, in Kotlin this does not work and throws an error

```
fun test(): Object {
    return "Bla"
}
```

When casting the string `return "Bla" as Object` it works. Interestingly, the Kotlin `Object` is imported from `java.utils` and is probably not the same Object as it is in the Java code.

Why is this so? Does Kotlin not want you to return such general objects? How would I go about achieving this in Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin uses `Any`.

Comment: *probably not the same Object as it is in the Java code* - it is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin the type hierarchy starts with `Any`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance

You could write:

```
fun test() : Any {
    return "Bla"
}
```

But `Any` isn't `Object`.

> Note: Any is not java.lang.Object; in particular, it does not have any members other than equals(), hashCode() and toString(). Please consult the Java interoperability section for more details.